# Get post array in dynamic input area jquery to insert batch codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I have to create a dynamic input so I use this jquery plugin  [: jquery add input area](http://www.usamimi.info/~sutara/sample/add-input-area/). This is just the piece of my input in html (Sorry, Its a little long code coz bootstrap tag):

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('', array('id' => 'upload', 'enctype' => "multipart/form-data")); ?>
        <div class="box-body no-padding">
            <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
                <label for="container">Container No</label>
                <input type="text" name="container" id="container" class="form-control"/>
            </div>


      //This is the dynamic input Area, I have two.
             <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                <label for="cek_kondisi">Cek Kondisi Top</label>
                <table id="list2" class="table table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th style="width: 70%">Item</th>
                            <th style="width: 20%">Kondisi</th>
                            <th style="width: 10%">Act</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>
                        <tr class="list2_var">
                            <td>
                                <select class="form-control" name="list2_item_0" id="list2_name_0">
                                    <option>Pilih jenis kerusakan... </option>
                                    <?php
                                    foreach ($top_item as $v) {
                                        echo '<option value =' . $v->ID_ITEM_INSPECTION . ' >' . $v->NOMOR_ITEM_INSPECTION . '    - ' . $v->NAMA_ITEM_INSPECTION . '</option>';
                                    }
                                    ?>
                                </select>

                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <select class="form-control" name="list2_kondisi_1" id="list2_name_1">
                                    <option></option>
                                    <?php
                                    foreach ($detail_condition as $v) {
                                        echo '<option value =' . $v->ID_ITEM . ' >' . $v->ALIAS . '    - ' . $v->NAME_ITEM . '</option>';
                                    }
                                    ?>
                                </select>
                            </td>

                            <td class="del_area04"><button class="list2_del btn btn-block btn-danger" type="button"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="list2_add btn btn-success">Add</a><br>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                <label for="cek_kondisi">Cek Kondisi Bottom</label>
                <table id="list3" class="table table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th style="width: 70%">Item</th>
                            <th style="width: 20%">Kondisi</th>
                            <th style="width: 10%">Act</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>
                        <tr class="list3_var">
                            <td>
                                <select class="form-control" name="list3_item_0" id="list3_name_0">
                                    <option>Pilih jenis kerusakan...</option>
                                    <?php
                                    foreach ($bottom_item as $v) {
                                        echo '<option value =' . $v->ID_ITEM_INSPECTION . ' >' . $v->NOMOR_ITEM_INSPECTION . '    - ' . $v->NAMA_ITEM_INSPECTION . '</option>';
                                    }
                                    ?>
                                </select>

                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <select class="form-control" name="list3_kondisi_1" id="list3_name_1">
                                    <option></option>
                                    <?php
                                    foreach ($detail_condition as $v) {
                                        echo '<option value =' . $v->ID_ITEM . ' >' . $v->ALIAS . '    - ' . $v->NAME_ITEM . '</option>';
                                    }
                                    ?>
                                </select>
                            </td>

                            <td class="del_area04"><button class="list3_del btn btn-block btn-danger" type="button"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="list3_add btn btn-success">Add</a><br>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
                <label>Comments</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="7" placeholder="Masukkan comment Anda" name="comments"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.box-body -->

        <div class="box-footer">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Submit</button>
        </div>
        <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

This is the jquery

```
$('#list2').addInputArea({
    after_add: function () {

    }
});
$('#list3').addInputArea();
```

With controller like this :

```
public function add_inspection() {      
    echo ("<pre>");
    print_r($this->input->post());
}
```

I got array like this :

```
Array
(
[condition] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
    )

[container] => EOLU-123456-7
[cleaning] => Y
[owner] => Eagletainer
[last_cargo] => 9
[vessel] => MV.WAN HAI 171
[insulation] => 2
[tare] => 1200
[gross] => 3000
[capacity] => 3000
[unit_type] => IMO 1
[date_of_manu] => 22071989
[name_manu] => PT.Test
[last25] => 22071989
[cert25] => Test
[last5] => 22071989
[cert5] => Test
[list2_item_0] => 1
[list2_kondisi_0] => 9
[list2_item_1] => 2
[list2_kondisi_1] => 
[list3_item_0] => 12
[list3_kondisi_0] => 9
[list3_item_1] => 13
[list3_kondisi_1] => 
[comments] => Test Comment
```

)

To minimize the perform of my database server, I want to use insert_batch. Based the code to insert batch on those [docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#inserting-data), it must have array parameter. 
So how, can I get the dynamic input into an array ? Based my Post Array, this is the dynamic input :

```
[list2_item_0] => 1
[list2_kondisi_0] => 9
[list2_item_1] => 2
[list2_kondisi_1] => 
[list3_item_0] => 12
[list3_kondisi_0] => 9
[list3_item_1] => 13
[list3_kondisi_1] =>
```

I need :

```
 $data = array(
    array(
            [list2_item_0] => 1
            [list2_kondisi_0] => 9
    ),
    array(
            [list2_item_1] => 2
            [list2_kondisi_1] => 
    )
   //SO ON, SO ON

 );
```

How can I make it true, I have stack on two days, any help it so appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First, the array of data to pass to insert_batch needs to use the column names in your database. I'm a little confused by your naming convention, but the result will be something like this:

```
 $data = array(
    array(
            'column1' => 1
            'column2' => 9
    ),
    array(
            'column1' => 2
            'column2' => 
    )
   //SO ON, SO ON

 );
```

I'm guessing a little here about how you organize things, but it seems like you need to

1. loop through your post variables
2. find the ones of the form "listn_item_m"
3. find the 'kondisi' post variable that matches: listn_kondisi_m
4. create an insert item that puts those values into
   the proper database columns.

I'm too uncertain of your actual naming convention to provide useful example code, but it would be roughly like

```
$data[] = array('column1' => $this->input->post($item), 'column2' => $this->input->post($kondisi);
```

where `$item` would be the name of the post variable you found in step 2, and `$kondisi` would be the matching variable you found in step 3.